# Valgrind: suppress one-time memory leaks

Tags: c, ubuntu, memory-leaks, valgrind

Valgrind reports multiple memory leaks in my program, some of which are recurring leaks (i.e. they occur in multiple blocks), but most of which are one-timers, i.e. allocations that happen at program initialization and that I don't care to take care of before the program exits. I know I can write suppression files to suppress leaks from specific libraries, functions etc., but I haven't found a way to suppress leaks a limited number of times. Is there a way of doing this?

Currently, I use a small program I wrote to filter Valgrind's report file from one-time leaks (so when a paragraph in the report file starts with `X bytes leaked in 1 blocks`, that paragraph is removed from the report file), but obviously I'd prefer to configure Valgrind to suppress these leaks instead, not least because my filter does nothing to keep the leak summary accurate.

I'm asking because the leaky initialization code is generated by a compiler that compiles to C from the language in which I'm writing my program and that I have little interest in modifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valgrind does not report errors for allocated memory that is still accessible at program exit, so you have bona fide leaks, even if the amount of memory leaked is fixed and (for the moment) inconsequential.  Consider actually freeing your pointers, or else ensuring that they do not go out of scope or get overwritten.  Under some circumstances you could use arrays instead of dynamically-allocated memory.

If you insist on using suppressions to silence reporting on genuine leaks, however, then make Valgrind do the work for you.  Add the option `--gen-suppressions=yes` (if you want to interactively select which suppressions to generate) or `--gen-suppressions=all` (to generate suppressions for all errors) to your `valgrind` command line.  You'll need to copy the suppression descriptors Valgrind outputs into your suppression file.